# What has happened to Dynamic LINQ?

Tags: dynamic-linq

I have a need to use dynamic LINQ where I can use variables in place of field names. Now I have done some googling and found that there is a sample for VS2008 where we can get this functionality.
My question is what has happened to this DLINQ ? It's been 4 years and I wonder whether it's made it into framework proper or some other new solutions have been invented to replace this? I only have my interest in DLINQ now so it is rather difficult to find further info on google, beside not knowing what exactly I am looking for other than 'better incarnation of DLINQ'. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: DLINQ also denotes distributed linq... perhaps "dynamic linq" has been renamed?

Answer (score 0):

This was never an "official" part of LINQ so has never been included in the framework.

The source was freely available and versions of it have appeared in [CodePlex](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) and on [GitHub](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)

The GitHub source appears to be the origin of the Nuget package

Answer (score 0):

I've resurrected Dynamic LINQ, adding support for .NET 4.0/4.5, added support documentation (a work in progress), and added lots of new features.

Here is the [link](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/) to the docs page, and from there, you can find the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library/) and [GitHub Project](https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic)